# Beamerarticle problem

Tags: errors, beamerarticle

I think I can apply for the award of shortest MWE. This MWE compiles and runs OK, but if I comment out the second line (i.e. use `beamerarticle`) I receive error messages about `xcolor` clash, already defined `beamer` internal symbols, etc. Otherwise, my environment works OK. Any idea?

```
\documentclass{beamer} 
%\usepackage{beamerarticle}

\begin{document}
A
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

`beamerarticle` is meant to be used with `article`, not with `beamer`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{beamerarticle}
```

You can then have the following structure:

```
%\documentclass{article}
%\usepackage{beamerarticle}
\documentclass{beamer} 

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
A
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

To change to article mode, uncomment-out the first two lines and comment out the third one.